# Set ID for each row in MySQL

Tags: mysql

I have a **table** with **3 columns**. The two of them contain some data, but the `id` column is set to `NULL`. I need to set an **id** for every row without hardcoding it. How can I make this?

Comment: Are you asking for a Primary key?

Comment: @Mihai I am. I'm new to MySQL so I forgot to call it a Primary key. Thanks for pointing it out.

Comment: You need an auto incremented primary key like @Mihai suggested

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Run this against your table to drop and recreate your id primary key column.

```
 ALTER TABLE yourtable DROP id; 
 ALTER TABLE yourtable ADD id INT PRIMARY KEY AUTO_INCREMENT FIRST;
```

Comment: I would also add `FIRST` at the end, so that it puts the `id` column in the beginning. It doesn't change anything, but I prefer to have the primay key as first (set of) column.

Comment: Good observation. I agree with that, I like having the first column be the primary key as well.

Answer (score 2):

https://bytes.com/topic/mysql/answers/652076-how-create-identity-column-mysql

Example from site:

```
CREATE TABLE table_name
(
   id INTEGER AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
   someData INTEGER,
   someOtherData INTEGER
)
```

Or if `table_name` already exists:

```
ALTER TABLE table_name ADD COLUMN id INTEGER AUTO_INCREMENT UNIQUE KEY;
```